# Create data frame with list comprehension if/else

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataframe using 1 list and 1 dictionary.

The first column is the word (equal to the list), the second the count (some words are in the dictionary with the correspondent count).

Example:

```
list = ['hi', 'hello', 'bye']
dict = {'hi': 10}

df = hi    10
     hello 0
     bye   0
```

What I want to do is do it using one list comp, something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[word, count] for word in list if word in dict.keys(): count = dict[word] else: count = 0 ], columns=['words', 'count'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be a bit more expressive while writing python using `dict.get` method which can be used to set default value if key does not exist.

```py
pd.DataFrame([[word, dct.get(word, 0)] for word in lst], columns=['words', 'count'])
```

I've replaced dict and list with dct and lst to avoid using reserved keywords.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're actually after a Pandas `Series` object. Here's how you can create one from a dictionary that solves your problem:

```py
>>> lst = ['hi', 'hello', 'bye']
>>> dct = {'hi': 10}

>>> pd.Series({k: dct.get(k, 0) for k in lst})
hi       10
hello     0
bye       0
dtype: int64
```

Or, if you want a DataFrame:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame([(k, dct.get(k, 0)) for k in lst], columns=['word', 'count'])
    word  count
0     hi     10
1  hello      0
2    bye      0
```